# Removing Duplicate string from for each loops

Tags: php, string, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am having an issue removing duplicates from the result of a foreach loop.

The problem more so is the process of how i have the data.

Here is grab the data i need.

```
$results = mysql_query($query);
     while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
            extract($rows);
```

I am trying to grab a column of `item_specifiations`. Within this column there are multiple data, separated by commas. Some items have more data that others, some are lacking certain data.

```
$specs = explode("," , $item_specification);
```

I separate the data using the above method.Then i run the loop to show the data for each item in the DB.

```
foreach($specs as $spec => $key ){
```

This now returns every data separated for each item (UPC, PRODUCT_NAME, ETC), which is exactly what i need. But i need only the "BRAND" of the item. So i do the following.

```
  if (strpos($key, 'Brand') === 0) {
        $brand = explode(':', $key);                
   }
```

Now the problem i am having is certain items having duplicate brand names.

So i want to remove any strings that are returning. The problem is, since this is a loop, there is no way to compare the strings with each other. Each is its own array, so i am dealing with multiple multi-dimensional arrays. I cant figure a way to push them into 1 array then compare, or using something like unique_array.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. I have been stuck for awhile.

Comment: You want to skip brands that are already found? Store it in array with brand key and check if key was already set. The real problem is database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_unique`:

```
    $var = [];
   foreach($specs as $spec => $key) {
     if(strpos($key,'Brand') === true ) {
        $brand[]= implode(',', array_unique(explode(', ',$key)));
     } 
   }

 print_r($brand);
```

Comment: Well i tried using you advice, but seems when i use this method i get the following : Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in

Comment: Is your specs an array?

Comment: yes .
array(9) { [0]=> string(33) "Type : Ceiling / Wall Bracket " [1]=> string(38) " Style/Adjustment : Tilt / Rotate " [2]=> string(76) " Fits Speaker Brand : Bose/Denon/Infinity/Insignia/Kenwood/LG/JVC/Onkyo " [3]=> string(78) " Fits Other Speaker Brand : Panasonic/Philips/Pioneer/Samsung/Sony/Yamaha " [4]=> string(34) " Features : Easy Installation " [5]=> string(38) " Brand : Video Security Solutions " [6]=> string(22) " MPN : ECORMS20B5 " [7]=> string(24) " UPC : 791090676571 " [8]=> string(24) " UPC : Does Not Apply" }

Comment: $specs is an array , but $key is a string. So when unique_array is used with $key it returns an error.

Comment: I think you want to search the Brand inside the string so you are using `strpos()`.

Comment: Array ( [0] => ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) 
Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /home/inventory/public_html/webstore/eshop/index.php on line 19

Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /home/inventory/public_html/webstore/eshop/index.php on line 20

Comment: I think you are search the brand word inside your string am I right?

Comment: Can you give me the output array of your `$rows`?

Comment: its too long of an output to post in the comments section

Comment: Include that in your question please.